# How Can I check flat list data?

Tags: react-native

I have a flatList to show my products. Now I want to check each row is exist in cart or not and show how many.

I have cart data and product data.

(This is for each product screen)

```
  <FlatList
      data={this.state.dataSource}
      keyExtractor={(item, index) => String(item.id)}
      extraData={this.state.dataSource}
      renderItem={({item}) =>


          <View style={{flex:1,height:'100%',marginTop:2,marginBottom:2}}>

            //Show Title
            <Text>{item.title} - {item.type}</Text>

            //Show Cost
            <Text>${item.cost}</Text>

            //Add to cart with every Press
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.setState({
                                                          productId:item.id,
                                                          productname:item.title,
                                                          productType:item.type,
                                                          productPrice:item.cost
                                                        }, this.decrementCount)} activeOpacity={0.5}>
                <AntDesign name="minus" size={15}/>
            </TouchableOpacity>

            //Show how many is in cart
            <Text>{How can I show count of product}</Text>

            //Delete from cart with every Press
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.setState({
                                                          productId:item.id,
                                                          productname:item.title,
                                                          productType:item.type,
                                                          productPrice:item.cost
                                                        }, this.incrementCount)} activeOpacity={0.5} style={{position:'absolute',left:48,top:10}}>
              <AntDesign name="plus" size={15} style={{color:'#fff'}}/>
            </TouchableOpacity>


          </View>
    }
    />
```

**this.state.datacart: (product value is category id)**

This is my data cart. I sholud check product is in this list or not.

```
Array [
  Object {
    "count": "1",
    "id": "413",
    "name": "T-Shirt",
    "price": 3000,
    "product": "4",
    "type": "One",
  },
  Object {
    "count": "1",
    "id": "414",
    "name": "T-Shirt",
    "price": 5000,
    "product": "5",
    "type": "Two",
  },
  Object {
    "count": "1",
    "id": "415",
    "name": "T-Shirt",
    "price": 3500,
    "product": "1",
    "type": "Three",
  },
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have a array for your cart and add new items to it and remove from it

```
state = { cartList: [] }

increaseCart = (product) => {
  const state = this.state;
  const index = state.cartList.findIndex(item => item.id == product.id);  
  if(index > -1) {
    state.cartList[index].count = state.cartList[index].count + 1;
  } else {
    product.count = 1;
    state.cartList.push(product);
  }

  this.setState( state );
}

decreaseCart = (product) => {
  const state = this.state;
  const index = state.cartList.findIndex(item => item.id == product.id);  
  if(index > -1) {
    state.cartList[index].count = state.cartList[index].count - 1;
    if(state.cartList[index].count <= 0)
      state.cartList.splice(index, 1);
  }

  this.setState( state );
}
```

Now you can check your cart array for the product count

```
renderCount = (product) => {
  var count = 0;
  const index = state.cartList.findIndex(item => item.id == product.id);  
  if(index > -1)
    count = state.cartList[index].count;

  return(
    <Text>{count}</Text>
  );
}
```

And finally this will be your renderItem:

```
  renderItem={({item}) =>


      <View style={{flex:1,height:'100%',marginTop:2,marginBottom:2}}>

        //Show Title
        <Text>{item.title} - {item.type}</Text>

        //Show Cost
        <Text>${item.cost}</Text>

        //Delete from cart with every Press
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.decreaseCart(item)} activeOpacity={0.5}>
            <AntDesign name="minus" size={15}/>
        </TouchableOpacity>

        //Show how many is in cart
        {this.renderCount(item)}

        //Add to cart with every Press
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.increaseCart(item)} activeOpacity={0.5} style={{position:'absolute',left:48,top:10}}>
          <AntDesign name="plus" size={15} style={{color:'#fff'}}/>
        </TouchableOpacity>


      </View>
}
```